# Return Python value to PHP and not have it display it

Tags: php, python, session, authentication, return

Currently I am executing Python scripts from PHP with:

```
<?php

    $output = shell_exec('python ../cgi-bin/admin_login.py');
    echo $output;

?>
```

Which is working fine. It displays all the data from the `print()` calls in the script.

But how can I actually return a value to PHP (and not have it display it as output)? Obviously delete that echo call but Python return doesn't seem to do anything.

The Python script is for a login process and handles all the MySQL work for that; I know limited PHP so that is why I am using Python for this.

After running the script, a result will be generated depending on if login was successful..

`e.g. LOGGEDIN, EMPTYUSR, EMPTYPW, WRONGPW.` All codes for what went wrong (or right) for further acting on by PHP.

e.g. if LOGGEDIN = True when returned, PHP should create a session so the rest of the site knows a user is logged in.

So what I want is a solution of running that Python from PHP and getting those return values back without displaying them on the page.

Any advice much appreciated, 
Ilmiont

Comment: Why not use Python for everything? There are really [great miniframeworks](http://flask.pocoo.org/) out there which will make developing much nicer and easier compared to what you are doing with the PHP/Python mix.

Comment: Try -c at the end of the  single quote '.......py -c'

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `shell_exec()`, use [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/function.exec.php) instead, then decide what to do depending of returned code.

```
<?php
  exec('python ../cgi-bin/admin_login.py', $output, $code);
  switch($code) {
    case 0:
      echo $output;
    break;
    // other case may follow
  }
?>
```

**WARNING** `exec()` only capture stdout, not stderr.
If you need to get full output use :

```
exec('python ../cgi-bin/admin_login.py 2>&1', $output, $code);
```